# Execute code when starting an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want when my application starts, to execute some code

```
   if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized){
           WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

There is a folder `App_start` at the project, but I didn't find any file that I can add this code. Do you know if there is a specific file that has this purpose?

Comment: Have you tried the `Application_Start` method of Global.asax.cs?

Comment: Related post - [How to run a method in ASP.net MVC only once when application Load Without calling it from Application_Start()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32392337/465053)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This kind of startup code typically goes in the `Application_Start()` method, **Global.asax.cs** file

Answer (score 41):

Put your code in static method inside a class.

```
public static class SomeStartupClass
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        // whatever code you need
    }
}
```

Save that in `App_Start`.  Now add it to `Global.asax`, along with the other code MVC initialises here:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

    SomeStartupClass.Init();
}
```

Now your startup code is separated nicely.

Comment: I've faced with the next problem: Startup's Configuration method executes every time, when user sends request to Web application (call controller's method). But I need to execute my method just only once, when I start application

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```